# ArrayList capacity increase numbers

Tags: java, arraylist

just a quick question. Can anyone confirm if the following is the correct sequence of the new size of an ArrayList after adding one element past the capacity? I know it grows with a factor of 1.5 but that + 1 in the source code makes me doubt my answer. It starts off with capacity of 10 but the reason I am asking is because I want to test the efficiency of add method against linked list when the size becomes very large. I learnt that average add is constant because of amortized analysis but I just want to confirm by actually working this out.

10, 15, 23, 35, 53, 80, 121.....

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The size of the ArrayList after adding one element is 1+its size before. Are you asking about the *capacity*?

Comment: I meant the capacity, I know the size is equal to the number of elements.

Comment: The capacity of the ArrayList depends upon its implementation; there is no specific requirement, other than adding elements is amortized constant.

Comment: You can explicitly set the capacity of ArrayList (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ensureCapacity-int-). You need to make it clear what exactly are you trying to estimate.

Comment: I am trying to measure the time differences between adding a element in an ArrayList past one its capacity when its size is huge vs an addition in a linkedlist. The nodes in a linkedlist are sparse, not sequential in memory like an arraylist so I want to know how much does it differ.

Comment: @codecode in that particular case `LinkedList` might be more performant, but it loses to `ArrayList` in the long run if you're just adding elements.

Comment: Yes that is what I have been taught but it doesn't hurt to actually see it. Add in LL is constant whereas AL is claimed to be constant under amortized analysis. But I want to check the strain on AL when adding just 1 element past the capacity so, I have to careful with numbers here and make sure they are actually correct.

Answer (score 1):

I did a testing, check the source below:

```java
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyArrayList<E> extends ArrayList<E> {
    private int capacity = 0;

    public MyArrayList() {
        super();
    }

    public MyArrayList(int capacity) {
        super(capacity);
    }


    public void printCapacity() {
        try {
            Field elementData = ArrayList.class.getDeclaredField("elementData");
            elementData.setAccessible(true);
            Object[] arr = (Object[]) elementData.get(this);
            if (arr.length != capacity) {
                capacity = arr.length;
                System.out.println("Capacity == " + arr.length);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

```java
public class ResizeDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyArrayList<Integer> myArrayList = new MyArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1002; i++) {
            myArrayList.add(i);
            myArrayList.printCapacity();
        }
    }
}
```

It prints:

```
Capacity == 10
Capacity == 15
Capacity == 22
Capacity == 33
Capacity == 49
Capacity == 73
Capacity == 109
Capacity == 163
Capacity == 244
Capacity == 366
Capacity == 549
Capacity == 823
Capacity == 1234
```

Answer (score 0):

As I know

```
newCapacity = (oldCapacity * 3)/2 + 1
```

So if your create an arrayList with capacity 10. The next value will be 16. Then 25,38 and so on.
The +1 I think is for cases, when current capacity is odd.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for confirming that. So that +1 is a calculated constant. I kept reading it everywhere that it frows by 1.5 times but they did not mention the +1.

Comment: It states in the Javadoc that no growth strategy is specified. This might be correct for a particular implementation, but it is not guaranteed.

Comment: @codecode added to the answer my assumption about +1.

Comment: But does it matter if it is odd or even? Everything is integer so the division will yield an int so I don't understand what the +1 is for? Maybe to accomodate the new element to be added?

Comment: @AndyTurner you are absolutely right. But I think, that  in most cases developers use java.util.ArrayList.

Comment: @codecode my assumption was, than when current capacity is odd, e.g. 15, if we simply multiply it for 1.5, the INT value will be 22, less then fair 1.5 if we have double (22.5).

Comment: @DanilaZharenkov the point of _Andy Turner_ was that the capacity strategy is not defined in the specification of `ArrayList` so it could be different on each version of the JDK.

Comment: you may to reword and expand your answer  a bit. use "old" instead of "current". Also, the +1 is to cover the result of `(oldCapacity * 3)` being an odd number, leading to a missing 0.5 at the end result (due of casting to int). It is just to ensure that a growth to a 1.5 capacity is being guaranteed.

Comment: Oh! So I have to check source code for JDK 9 then. Thank you all for the help. I have to be careful with numbers to actually see the difference.

Comment: Thanks KarelG for the explanation.

Comment: No this answer is incorrect. The behaviour changed between 6b-27 and 7b-147 of the OpenJDK.

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out in comment, Java does not specify any behaviour for this: it is the implementation of that API that determines how expansion of `ArrayList` will work.

But if you are asking about the behaviour of the OpenJDK implementation then a simple way to find the answer is to look at the source code. In this case     [`ArrayList.grow`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.grow%28int%29)

```
private void grow(int minCapacity) {
    // overflow-conscious code
    int oldCapacity = elementData.length;
    int newCapacity = oldCapacity + (oldCapacity >> 1);
    if (newCapacity - minCapacity < 0)
        newCapacity = minCapacity;
    if (newCapacity - MAX_ARRAY_SIZE > 0)
        newCapacity = hugeCapacity(minCapacity);
    // minCapacity is usually close to size, so this is a win:
    elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, newCapacity);
}

private static int hugeCapacity(int minCapacity) {
    if (minCapacity < 0) // overflow
        throw new OutOfMemoryError();
    return (minCapacity > MAX_ARRAY_SIZE) ?
        Integer.MAX_VALUE :
        MAX_ARRAY_SIZE;
}
```

So the logic is actually quite complex depending on size of array. But in the simplest case, if the old capacity is `c` then the new capacity is `c + c/2`.

In older versions it was `3c/2+1` but that changed in recent implementations.

Which just shows that it's worth checking the source!